# Creating a countdown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

Im trying to convert this code:

```
var timerId;
var counter;

function start() {
  console.log('start');
  if (!counter) {
    reset();
  } else {
    loop();
  }
}

function pause() {
  console.log('pause');
  if (timerId) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = null;
  }
}

function reset() {
  console.log('reset');
  pause();
  counter = 10;
  loop();
}

function loop() {
  timerId = setInterval(function() {
    if (0 >= counter) {
      pause();
      return;
    }
    console.log('counter', counter);
    counter--;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Into react with useEffect. Basically I am creating a quiz type app where people type in the answer and theres a timer and for every time they get an answer right, the timer resets. I also need the value of the timer before it resets.
This is what I have so far:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Play = (props) => {
  // const { username } = props.match.params;

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [currentWord, setCurrentWord] = useState("");

  const [wordArray, setWordArray] = useState([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const [inputtedWord, setInputtedWord] = useState("");

  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(1);

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsername(props.location.state.username);

    let wordArr = ["apple", "pear", "treehouse"];
    setWordArray(wordArr);

    setCurrentWord(wordArr[counter]);
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  }, []);

  // const countDown = () => {
  //   setTimer((timer) => timer - 1);
  // };

  // const pauseTimer = () => {
  //   setCurrentTime(timer);
  //   stopTimer();
  // };

  // const stopTimer = () => {
  //   setTimer(-1);
  //   clearInterval(interval);
  // };

  let interval;
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   interval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

  //   return function cleanup() {
  //     stopTimer();
  //   };
  // }, []);


  const handleTextChange = (e) => {
    let textInput = e.target.value;

    setInputtedWord(textInput);
    if (textInput === currentWord) {
      correctWord();
    }
  };

  const correctWord = () => {
    let jso = {
      counter,
      word: wordArray[counter - 1],
    };
    console.log(jso);
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    pauseTimer();
    setCurrentWord(wordArray[counter]);
    setScore(score + 10);
    setInputtedWord("");
  };

  if (timer === -1) {
    stopTimer();
    return <Redirect to="/leaderboard" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="play-container container">
      <span className="instructions">Type the word</span>
      <span className="generated-word">{currentWord}</span>
      <input
        value={inputtedWord}
        // ref={inputContainer}
        type="text"
        className="text-input"
        onChange={(e) => handleTextChange(e)}
      />
      <div className="scoreboard">
        <div className="level scoreboard-item">
          <span className="level-label label">Level</span>
          <span className="level-value">{level}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="time scoreboard-item">
          <span className="time-label label">Time</span>
          <span className="time-value">{timer}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="score scoreboard-item">
          <span className="score-label label">Score</span>
          <span className="score-value">{score}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Play;
```

Ive tried alot of things and nothing worked so far. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but here is a functional timer where when it reset you can see that time run out, and when they submit it resets the timer and tells you what the value of the timer was:

```js
// Example stateless functional component
const Example = props => {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = React.useState(5);
  const [guess, setGuess] = React.useState('');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          if (countdown === 0) {
              console.log('Time up, next question');
          }
          setCountdown(countdown ? countdown - 1 : 5);
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
  }, [countdown]);
  
  const submit = () => {
      
      setCountdown(5);
  };
  
  const makeGuess = (e) => {
      const value = e.target.value;
      if (value === 'hello') {
          console.log(`CORRECT! Timer was at ${countdown}`);
          setCountdown(5);
          setGuess('');
      } else {
          setGuess(value)
      }
  }
  
  return (<div>Enter hello: <input value={guess} onChange={makeGuess}/>{countdown}</div>)
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"/>
```

Comment: I need to programmatically reset and start up the timer once the answer is correct in the correctWord function